# Is there a way to retrieve cookies from multiple devices at the same network?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cookies, automation, lan

So I am thinking about making an application (preferably a mobile app) that uses the preferences (hobbies, interests etc.) of everyone in the same room, with his/her device connected to the same network, to provide specialized entertainment to a company of friends. It would be better if everyone wouldn't have to download any software or something, for the sake of comfort. Is there a way to achieve something like that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do the list of hobbies come from? A server can't 'gather' cookies from random devices on a network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read How to Ask. and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. please provide what have you already tried for more understanding of the problem